# Emacs-mac real state

Tags: macos, emacs

New to mac! I just installed railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport and I see that there are two top bars. The normal topbar of applications and one for tabs (it seems).

My question is, can I get rid of the tabs (create a new tab). Being an emacs user I have no use for tabs at all!!

Comment: Never mind `'(mac-toggle-tab-bar)` hides the tab bar.

Comment: Your solution with ` mac-toggle-tab-bar` is worth to be put in an answer. Do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs doesn't support tab bar out of the box.
You can put `(tool-bar-mode -1)` in your init.el file to turn off the tool bar.

Are you in GUI mode or from terminal? I am guessing the tab might come from your terminal app like `iterm`. For Emacs use GUI version. Better support for modifier keys and can display images and pdf...

Comment: I mentioned that I was using `railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport` which is a port customized for macs. This is not an emacs issue at all but the OSX port. It seems that in current OSX you can "tab" everything and the emacs port tries to stay true in this regards. FYI, I'm using GUI mode.

Comment: I am using the same port but never seen a tab. weird.. There are a few build flag you can use. Maybe check out those options. I just download it's prebuild binary and see now tab either.

Comment: I would love to see what those flags are. New to mac, got my first macbook pro 3 days ago. The documentation seems a little sparse on this emacs port. I came to mac from linux and been using for the last 200 years! Can you please point me to documented flags for this emacs port flags?

Comment: https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport at the very end mostly to do with the title bar nothing to do with the tab bar u mention. Maybe post a picture of that tab bar? I never seen a tab bar with Emacs expect with 3rd party package which I never use.